# correct way to store an exception in a variable

Tags: c++, exception

I have an API which internally has some exceptions for error reporting. The basic structure is that it has a root exception object which inherits from `std::exception`, then it will throw some subclass of that.

Since catching an exception thrown in one library or thread and catching it in another can lead to undefined behavior (at least Qt complains about it and disallows it in many contexts). I would like to wrap the library calls in functions which will return a status code, and if an exception occurred, a copy of the exception object.

What is the best way to **store** an exception (with it's polymorphic behavior) for later use? I believe that the c++0x future API makes use of something like this. So what is the best approach?

The best I can think of is to have a `clone()` method in each exception class which will return a pointer to an exception of the same type. But that's not very generic and doesn't deal with standard exceptions at all.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: It seems that c++0x will have [a mechanism for this](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#rethrow). It is described as "library magic". Does that mean that is doesn't require any of the language features of c++0x? if not, are there any implementations which are compatible with c++03?

**EDIT**: Looks like boost has an [implementation of exception copying](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/exception/doc/current_exception.html). I'll keep the question open for any non `boost::copy_exception` answers.

**EDIT**: To address j_random_hacker's concerns about the root cause of the exception being an out of memory error. For this particular library and set of exceptions, this is not the case. All exceptions derived from the root exception object represent different types of parsing errors caused by invalid user input. Memory related exceptions will simply cause a `std::bad_alloc` to be thrown which is addressed separately.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of C++11, this can be done using std::exception_ptr.

(I use this in a class that makes an std::thread interruptible provided that the underlying thread implementation is a POSIX thread. To handle exceptions that may be thrown in the user's code - which causes problems if they are thrown in a certain critical section of my implementation - I store the exception using std::exception_ptr, then throw it later once the critical section has completed.)

To store the exception, you catch it and store it in the ptr variable.

```
std::exception_ptr eptr;
try {
    ... do whatever ...
} catch (...) {
    eptr = std::current_exception();
}
```

You can then pass eptr around wherever you like, even into other threads (according to the docs - I haven't tried that myself). When it is time to use (i.e. throw) it again, you would do the following:

```
if (eptr) {
    std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
}
```

If you want to examine the exception, you would simply catch it.

```
try {
    if (eptr) {
        std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
    }
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    ... examine e ...
} catch (...) {
    ... handle any non-standard exceptions ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have what would be what I think is your best, only answer.  You can't keep a reference to the original exception because it's going to leave scope.  You simply have to make a copy of it and the only generic way to do that is with a prototype function like clone().

Sorry.

Comment: But beware that the root cause of the exception may be an out-of-memory condition, in which case `clone()` will fail if it tries to call `new`. This can be gotten around, e.g. by overloading `operator new()` for each exception type to allocate from a static buffer, but it's not necessarily pretty either.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Well, since we are getting pedantic, what you call out-of-memory is better called bad-alloc and it doesn't have to be actual out of memory. Another reason for bad-alloc is requesting too much memory, and in that case subsequent small allocations will succeed

Comment: @sbk: Is it really pedantic to consider the possibility of running out of memory?

Comment: The easy answer here is to point out that with bad_alloc you're a) screwed, and b) getting a particular exception that you're not going to be able to clone since it won't be your own.

Answer (score 2):

You're allowed to throw anything, including pointers. You could always do something like this:

```
throw new MyException(args);
```

And then in the exception handler store the caught pointer, which will be fully polymorphic (below assuming that `MyException` derives from `std::exception`):

```
try {

   doSomething(); // Might throw MyException*

} catch (std::exception* pEx) {

   // store pEx pointer
}
```

You just have to be careful about memory leaks when you do it this way, which is why throw-by-value and catch-by-reference is normally used.

More about catch-by-pointer: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.8

Comment: The problem with this solution as I see it is that you might be throwing an exception due to something that has as its root cause an out-of-memory condition, in which case `new` will fail.

Comment: That's mentioned in the link, but you could in theory work around that by having a pre-allocated or static out-of-memory exception that you throw in that case. But then you would need to make sure that you don't delete this as you would your other exceptions. It's do-able but you have to be careful of a lot of pitfalls like this.

Comment: Couldn't we check to see if the exception indicates an out of memory condition and simply set an int/boolean to indicate this?

Comment: +1: For my particular use can this isn't a bad idea. similar to the clone approach but doing at the point of the throw.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why catching an exception thrown in one library and catching it in another can lead to undefined behavior is that these libraries could be linked with different Runtime libraries. If you will return exception from a function instead of throwing it you will not avoid that problem.

Comment: I believe you are correct, I think the issue Qt has with it is more about passing between threads (I've added that subtlety to my question as well).

Answer (score 0):

My utility library has an `AnyException` class that is basically the same as `boost::any` without the casting support.  Instead, it has a `Throw()` member that throws the original object stored.

```
struct AnyException {
  template<typename E>
  AnyException(const E& e) 
    : instance(new Exception<E>(e))
  { }

  void Throw() const {
    instance->Throw();
  }

private:
  struct ExceptionBase {
    virtual void Throw() const =0;
    virtual ~ExceptionBase() { }
  };

  template<typename E>
  struct Exception : ExceptionBase {
    Exception(const E& e)
      : instance(e)
    { }

    void Throw() const {
      throw std::move(instance);
    }

  private:
    E instance;
  };
  ExceptionBase* instance;
};
```

This is a simplification, but that's the basic framework.  My actual code disables copying, and has move semantics instead.  If needed, you can add a virtual `Clone` method to the `ExceptionBase` easily enough... since `Exception` knows the original type of the object, it can forward the request onto the actual copy constructor, and you immediately have support for all copiable types, not just ones with their own `Clone` method.

When this was designed, it was not meant for storing caught exceptions... once an exception was thrown, it propagated as normal, so out-of-memory conditions were not considered.  However, I imagine you could add an instance of `std::bad_alloc` to the object, and store it directly in those situations.

```
struct AnyException {
   template<typename E>
   AnyException(const E& e) {
      try {
          instance.excep = new Exception<E>(e);
          has_exception = true;
      } catch(std::bad_alloc& bad) {
          instance.bad_alloc = bad;
          bas_exception = false;
      }
   }

   //for the case where we are given a bad_alloc to begin with... no point in even trying
   AnyException(const std::bad_alloc& bad) {
     instance.bad_alloc = bad;
     has_exception = false;
   }

   void Throw() const {
     if(has_exception)
         instance.excep->Throw();
     throw instance.bad_alloc;
   }

 private:
   union {
     ExceptionBase* excep;
     std::bad_alloc bad_alloc;
   } instance;
   bool has_exception;
 };
```

I haven't actually tested that second bit at all... I might be missing something glaringly obvious that will prevent it from working.