# Boost equivalent of std::async()

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, c++11

Without using `boost::thread` and `boost::bind` directly, is there a way to implement the equivalent of the following code?

```
std::string func()
{
    std::string str("Hello from async task!");
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    auto ftr = std::async(&func);
    std::cout << "Hello from main!";
    std::string str = ftr.get();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;      
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, this part: `auto ftr = std::async(&func);` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Certainly. Simply make `async<T>(std::function<T()>)` return a future which invokes `func()` the moment it's first waited-for. You won't get any asynchronicity, but the API doesn't actually guarantee that the function will run asynchronously, so that's not a problem.

If you have access to an OS-specific threading library, you could of course use that as well.

Note, however, that storing exceptions cannot be implemented portably; it requires additional support from the C++ implementation, unless you can restrict the exceptions supported to ones with a polymorphic clone function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960554/correct-way-to-store-an-exception-in-a-variable) for more information.

The final implementation might look a bit like this (untested):

```
// NOTE - we assume a SINGLE THREADED environment

template<typename T>
class myfuture_detail {
    mutable boost::variant<T, boost::function<T()> > val;

public:
    myfuture_detail(const boost::function<T()> &f)
        : val(f) { }

    const T &get() const {
        if (T *t = boost::get<T>(&val)) {
            return *t;
        } else {
            boost::function<T()> f = *boost::get<boost::function<T> >(&val);
            val = f();

            T *t = boost::get<T>(&val);
            assert(t);

            return *t;
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class myfuture {
    boost::shared_ptr<myfuture_detail<T> > ptr;

public:
    myfuture(const boost::function<T()> &f)
        : ptr(boost::make_shared<myfuture_detail<T> >(f))
    {}

    myfuture() { }

    const T &get() const {
        return ptr->get();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I'm something of a novice in terms of meta programming so I'm not sure how this could be used in the same way as the example in the OP... For example, where would the equivalent of `std::async()` come into it? Does the `myfuture` class need to somehow be bound to a `boost::thread` ?

Comment: This is not actually asynchronous. `std::async`'s contract does not actually guarentee that the async routine will run... asynchronously. Consider if the async thread is never scheduled until you get to the `.get()` - it's effectively synchronous. This is what I've done here - since you have no threads, I just pretend like it was running asynchronously and just happened to not get anything done until you came looking for the result.

Comment: "*Note, however, that storing exceptions cannot be implemented portably*" Doesn't [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/libs/exception/) do this?

Comment: @ildjarn, that requires either non-portable compiler support, or use of the `enable_current_exception` construct at the throw point