# Boost Bind to Method

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-bind

I'm trying to use boost thread to multi-thread one of my applications.

The part I have an issue with is the `boost::bind`.

Here is what I am trying to do :

```
boost::bind(&Class::CalculateRT(i, i - 1), RT));
```

Considering :

```
RT is a TransformType 
typedef std::pair<Eigen::Matrix3d, Eigen::Vector3d> TransformType;
```

And CalculateRT is a method : 
`TransformType Class::CalculateRT(int i, int j)` which returns, as you can guess, RT .

What I want is to be able to bind my method, get what it returns (RT) and then thread it with something like :

```
boost::thread MultiThreadingRTCalculation(boost::bind(&Class::CalculateRT(i, i - 1), RT));
```

I'm pretty sure I'm using bind wrong by putting RT as second argument.

After looking through some other StackOverflow questions, I tried something like this :

```
boost::function<TransformType()> BoostFunction(boost::bind(&Class::CalculateRT(i, i - 1), RT));
```

All of these do not show an error in VS2013 until compile time, which pops a : error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::' error.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class::CalculateRT(i, i - 1)` is a function call, and you try to take address of call itself...

try something like: `boost::bind(&Class::CalculateRT, i, i - 1)` (address to bind to, arguments follow).

`boost::ref(i)` might be needed if you want it to return different values for different i.

Is this static method? Then it needs value for `this` in bind.

`RT` will be result of binding call:

```
boost::function<TransformType()> boundFunction = bind(........);
TransformType RT = boundFunction();
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing and seems to be working : 

`boost::function<TransformType()> boundFunction = bind(........);    
TransformType RTtest = boundFunction();  
boost::thread BT(boundFunction); `

        
I was wondering if I could pass an argument to boundFunction such as :
 ` boost::bind(&Class::CalculateRT, i, i - j)  
RT = boundFunction(j); `

It might be asking too much x) ?

Comment: in bind use `_1` (from `boost/bind/placeholders.hpp` ) instead of i. In binded function it will expand to 'first passed argument'. And change `boost::function` type to `<TransformType(int)>`

Comment: That's actually what I tried using but I got this after : 
Error 24 error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments C:\Libraries\boost_1_57_0\boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp
  
      This is what I did : 

`boost::function<TransformType(int,int)> boundFunction2 = boost::bind(&Class::CalculateRT, this, _1, _2);  
TransformType RT = boundFunction(i,j);  
boost::thread BT(boundFunction); `

I also tried `boost::thread BT(boundFunction(i,j)) ` but to no avail.

Edit: (Why aren't my Linebreaks working :( ? )

Comment: @Zepherus: Keep in mind that the `RT = boundfunction()` calls the bound function immediately, storing the result in `RT`. The thread then calls the boudn function _again_, but this time discarding the result.

Comment: @Zepherus problem is in `boost::thread BT(boundFunction);` - this  thread constructor requires zero argument function as it's argument. Try `boost::thread BT(boundFunction, i, j);` it will create thread and call boundFunction in it with i and j as params

Comment: @MSalters Not quite sure I understand this part : " The thread then calls the boudn function again, but this time discarding the result" . Would you mind explaining ? Why would it call the function twice? 

at Hcorg : Yup, that works I think (compiles at least). I guess I'm not used to passing the arguments after, I need to get my head around it..

Comment: @Zepherus: You probably don't **want** to call `boundFunction` twice. But `RT = boundFunction(i,j)` is the first call, and `std::thread(boundFunction, i, j)` is the second call. And the assignment to RT happens on the first call, not on the second (threaded) call. Furthermore, using `_1` and `_2` placeholders means that you have left both parameters unbound. That is to say, your bound function actually has 0 bound arguments. Technically that's still a bound function, but practically speaking it's pointless.

Comment: @MSalters Ugh, then it's clearly not doing what I want at all. 

I would like to thread the CalculateRT method so that I can have, For example. : 
RT = ....   with i and i-1 
RT2 = ...  with i and i-2
RT3 =...  with i and i-3

"Wait for all CalculateRT to finish"  <-- with .join() ;

Comment: @Zepherus: That was my feeling, which is why I gave my answer. And as you now describe it, the `std::async` forms appear to be even more appropriate. You'd create 3 `std::async` tasks, and call `.get` three times. (The third call could also use the foreground thread if that's convenient).

Comment: @MSalters humm.. Any reason why you're using std namespace instead of boost:: ?

I'm trying this : 

auto background = boost::sync(boost::launch::async, (&Class::CalculateRT, i, i - 1)); but it's giving me a ' a namespace is not allowed for the boost::sync'

Comment: @Zepherus: C++11 adopted a lot of Boost code into the standard. So there is quite a strong relation between the two namespaces. The `std::` versions are directly supported by the compiler vendors and may use more advanced optimalization.

Comment: @MSalters I figured as much. But I would rather use Boost, just because C++11 would incur some hassle on other aspects... 

What should I use instead of .get (which it doesn't seem to have? ) the boost::sync doesn't seem valid either..

Comment: @Zepherus: StackOverflow really has a good search, you should try it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876459/boost-equivalent-of-stdasync

Comment: @MSalters I've tried multiple things (even using the std::async, but to no avail.. This is where I'm at if you want to take a look : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750834/boostasync-for-multiple-function-calls-threading  )

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding what `bind` does. It binds arguments. I.e. It can turn `Foo(x,y)` into `Foo(3,y)` by binding `x=3`. You don't bind return values.

Instead, what you need is a lambda: `[&RT, i](){RT = Class::CalculateRT(i, i - 1)`

Of course, if `CalculateRT` is a non-static method, then you need a `Class` object from somewhere.

To use:

```
TransformType RT;
auto boundFunction = [&RT, i](){RT = Class::CalculateRT(i, i - 1);
std::thread(boundFunction).detach(); // Doesn't wait for the assignment!
```

Of course, if you want to rely on the result of RT, you can `join()` the thread instead. But at that point, do you really need a thread and a bound function?

```
 auto background = std::sync(std::launch::async, &Class::CalculateRT, i,i-1);
 // Do stuff in the foreground.
  RT = background.get();
```

Comment: I choose the other answer as solution as that is what worked for me, I started out by trying what you suggested but I must admit It wasn't successful (probably from my lack of knowledge about lambdas than your explanation).

Comment: @Zepherus: There might be an even simpler solution, I think - see update.